# Hibernate Auto Increment ID

Tags: java, hibernate, auto-increment

I have a j2ee application using hibernate with annotation. How do I annotate the Id field in my pojo class to set it as auto increment or auto generated. and in adding the bean do I leave that field in my bean null?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

and you leave it `null` (`0`) when persisting. (`null` if you use the `Integer` / `Long` wrappers)

In some cases the `AUTO` strategy is resolved to `SEQUENCE` rathen than to `IDENTITY` or `TABLE`, so you might want to manually set it to `IDENTITY` or `TABLE` (depending on the underlying database).

It seems **`SEQUENCE`** + **specifying the sequence name** worked for you.

Comment: my id is of type string. what will i set to it. Because I get this error.


Caused by: javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value

Comment: autoincrement means it is a number which is incremented. A String cannot be incremented. Make the column int

Comment: myid column in the database is of type number. And i already changed my id in my pojo to int. i get the error sequence does not exist

Comment: you didn't say what your database is. Try setting it to IDENTITY, rathen than AUTO.

Comment: imusing oracle database. when i set it to identity it gives this error
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Dialect does not support identity key generation

Here's my dialect
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

Comment: For Oracle, SEQUENCE is the closest thing to autoincrement.  You have to create the sequence ahead of time unless you're letting Hibernate generate your schema. If you think you might support multiple databases at some point, use TABLE.

Comment: Well, in fact, I'm also using Oracle with AUTO and it works like charm

Comment: Don't use identity, Oracle does not support identity, it supports sequence.

Comment: This worked for me...

  @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="gen_USERS") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="gen_USERS", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ")@Column(name="ID")

Comment: @Bozho Is there any strategy which gives the next ID available to the added object? What I mean by that is if I delete the last object from a table with ID 5, will the new added element get the ID 5? I've used almost all strategies and it always gives it the 6 ID. Is there any way to make it happen?

Answer (score 36):

Do it as follows :-

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="kaugen" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="kaugen")
@Column(name="proj_id")
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
 }
```

You can use any arbitrary name instead of kaugen.
It worked well, I could see below queries on console

```
Hibernate: select max(proj_id) from javaproj
Hibernate: insert into javaproj (AUTH_email, AUTH_firstName, AUTH_lastName, projname,         proj_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: This one works for me. But it don't let me set ID value. I tried to setID with integers or int, but it uses max anytime. What should I do?

Comment: use @GenericGenerator(name="incrementId",strategy="assigned")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="incrementId").It will allow you to set id by your own.But if you not pass id then it will be 0.

Comment: @Kaushik Lele Is strategy="increment" hibernate inbuilt increment stratergy ? Is it comes under which of these SEQUENCE,IDENTITY,AUTO,TABLE ?

Comment: How about 700 millions records in table? This could be the issue without index I think

Answer (score 13):

FYI

Using **netbeans** *New Entity Classes from Database* with a **mysql** *auto_increment* column, creates you an attribute with the following annotations:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
@NotNull
private Integer id;
```

This was getting me the same an error saying the column must not be null, so i simply removed the @NotNull anotation leaving the attribute null, and it works!

Answer (score 10):

Hibernate defines five types of identifier generation strategies:

**AUTO** - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB

**TABLE** - table holding the id

**IDENTITY** - identity column

**SEQUENCE** - sequence

**identity copy** – the identity is copied from another entity

Example using Table

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE , generator="employee_generator")
@TableGenerator(name="employee_generator", 
                table="pk_table", 
                pkColumnName="name", 
                valueColumnName="value",                            
                allocationSize=100) 
@Column(name="employee_id")
private Long employeeId;
```

for more details, check the [link](http://supportmycode.com/2014/08/21/generating-the-identifier-property-generatedvaluestrategygenerationtype-table/).

Answer (score 6):

If you have a numeric column that you want to auto-increment, it might be an option to set `columnDefinition` directly. This has the advantage, that the schema auto-generates the value even if it is used without hibernate. This might make your code db-specific though:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial") // PostgreSQL
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment") // MySql
```

Comment: MySQL is @Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment")

Comment: Postgress is columnDefinition = "serial"

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone "bumps" in this SO question in search for strategies for **Informix** table when **PK** is type **Serial**.

I have found that this works...as an example.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "special_serial_pk")
private Integer special_serial_pk;
```

For this to work make sure when you do **session.SaveOrUpdate** you pass the value for the column **special_serial_pk** **NULL**  .

In my case i do an **HTML** **POST** with **JSON** like so...

```
{
"special_serial_pk": null, //<-- Field to be incremented
"specialcolumn1": 1,
"specialcolumn2": "I love to code",
"specialcolumn3": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using netbeans New Entity Classes from Database with a mysql *auto_increment* column, creates you an attribute with the following hibernate.hbm.xml:
id is auto increment