# autoincrement in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the ID of my table set to autoincrement in MySql 5.1

How do I map my Hibernate  with autoincrements set in DBMS?

I tried this way :

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
<generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
```

Though it doesn't show any error, it does not add anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Auto Increment ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id)

Comment: I guess that guy asked about annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
<generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

if you are using hibernate to generate ddl (using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property set to create or update) the system would generate scripts which would set autoincrement on the id column.