# How to annotate id so it's autoincrements without SEQUENCE table?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence, auto-generate

I have a trouble generating id's for new entities, i tried:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long myId;
```

and

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
private Long myId;
```

but on `entityManager.persist` i get `Table "SEQUENCE" not found`
In pure hibernate `generator class="increment"` worked for me just fine.

Comment: H2 database. generator class="increment" worked in pure hibernate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could define myId as *auto increment / identity column* in database and annotate corresponding field entity following way:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long myId;
```

That works at least with H2 1.3.160 & Hibernate 3.6.8.

Comment: I want to stress how important it is that the database column be defined as AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this..

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: tries to query SEQUENCE table

Comment: which db are you using ? maybe this link might have more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id

Answer (score 0):

If you like to generate IDs that are shared (and unique) between multiple persisted objects use the @TableGenerator. H2 and many other databases don't have internal support for sequences so @SequenceGenerator doesn't work.

Here's a quick example to have a unique/shared @Id across two objects:

```
@Entity
public class Class1 {

  // setting pkColumnValue of TableGenerator is very important ;-)
  @Id
  @TableGenerator(
      name = "guid", 
      initialValue = 0, 
      allocationSize = 10, 
      table = "GUID_SEQ", 
      pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", 
      valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", 
      pkColumnValue = "GUID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "guid")
  private long id;
}


@Entity
public class Class2 {

  // use the same pkColumnValue 
  @Id
  @TableGenerator(
      name = "guid", 
      initialValue = 0, 
      allocationSize = 10, 
      table = "GUID_SEQ", 
      pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", 
      valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", 
      pkColumnValue = "GUID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "guid")
  private long id;
}
```