# Generate ID based on number of rows in table in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, entity

I am developing a spring 3 MVC application. I am using hibernate as the ORM. While defining the model, i have an ID field. I want to auto generate it in such a way that its value is the current number of rows in the table + 1. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` column or a sequence will do the trick. In Hibernate simply annotate `id` with `@GeneratedValue`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Hibernate will automatically set the id to next available value.

## See also

- [Hibernate Auto Increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id)

Comment: hi. the issues here is that certain elements may be deleted at some time. in this case, when i add a new element, the id is not in sequence but is equal to the total number of elements added at one point to the table.

Comment: @KaushikBalasubramanain: I know. But imagine: when you add three records they will have 1, 2 and 3 ids, right? Then when you delete first or second and add another one, according to your algorithm it should have id 3 (2 records in the database exist at a time) - but record with such id already exists!