# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: dept_id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts-1

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: dept_id
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.atom.HibernateOne.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at com.atom.HibernateOne.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.atom.HibernateOne.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: dept_id
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1164)
    at com.atom.HibernateOne.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
```

---

department table

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
    `dept_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dept_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`dept_id`)
)
;
```

employeeo table

```
CREATE TABLE `employeeo` (
    `employee_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `birth_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cell_phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deptest.departmentt_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
    INDEX `FK_DEPT` (`dept_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_DEPT` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`dept_id`)
);
```

---

department.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.atom.HibernateOne">

     <class name="com.atom.HibernateOne.Department" table="department">

        <id name="departmentId" type="java.lang.Long" column="dept_id" >
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="departmentName" column="DEPT_NAME"/>

        <set name="employees" 
             table="EMPLOYEEO"
             inverse="true" 
             fetch="select">

            <key>
                <column name="dept_id" 
                        not-null="true" />
            </key>

            <one-to-many class="com.atom.HibernateOne.EmployeeO" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

employeeo.hbm.xml

```
 <class name="com.atom.HibernateOne.EmployeeO" table="EMPLOYEE">
    <id name="employeeId" column="EMPLOYEE_ID">
    </id>

    <property name="firstname" column="FIRSTNAME"/>
    <property name="lastname" column="LASTNAME" />
    <property name="birthDate" type="date" column="BIRTH_DATE" />
    <property name="cellphone" column="CELL_PHONE" />


    <many-to-one name="department" class="com.atom.HibernateOne.Department" fetch="select">
        <column name="dept_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

</class>
```

*** Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: dept_id***

I am not able to understand the occurrence of error

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is because you doesn't declare dept_id as auto increment in your java code. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id) for more info

Comment: within hbm.xml files under <id> tag** <generator class="identity" /> ** is doing that thing for me,