# Persisting with Entity Manager into MySQL on a table with auto increment PK

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

I am following the NetBeans E-commerce tutorial - on the 9th Tutorial which is about Integrating Transnational Business Logic

Where they show how create the `OrderManager` class with `placeOrder()` Method - and the method is transactional which involves three tables - first `customer`, then `customer_order` and finally `orderedItem` using `em.persist()`.

but the `em.persist()` method is not persisting for customer - but it will persist for customer if I manually supplied the customer id manually into the code (hard code).

but for the `customer_order` it will not persist even after persisting the customer by manual id provision and using `em.flush()`;

I googled and couldn't seem to find way out. P.S. The Entity class is generated with Netbeans wizard - and the id generation strategy IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

The `em.persist()` was not persisting because the `@NotNull` annotation on the `id` fields was not allowing null - as I am working on Netbeans.

so removing those `@NotNull` or commenting them out on the entity class gets the job done.

infact I learned this fact from the last post of the following link.

[Hibernate Auto Increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id)