# Generated value exception java jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using spring jpa with Mysql.

I am trying to implement the folowing solution for bypassing the generated id field: [Bypass GeneratedValue in Hibernate (merge data not in db?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194721/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate-merge-data-not-in-db)

The problem is that when the id is null and should be generated I get : "field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

My entity:

```
    @Entity
public class RegistrationDetails{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "IdOrGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.xxx.common.UseIdOrGenerate")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
}
```

my generator:

```
    public class UseIdOrGenerate extends IdentityGenerator {

        @Override
        public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {

        if (obj == null)
            throw new HibernateException(
                         new NullPointerException());

        if ((((RegistrationDetails) obj).getId()) == null) {
            Serializable id = super.generate(
                             session,
                             obj);
            return id;
        }
        else {
     return ((RegistrationDetails) obj).getId();

        }
        }

}
```

From some conversations I think it something about the Auto increment filed but I cant add it in MySql.

EDIT:
My tables are generated automatically when the tomcat server starts. the problem is that it doesn't set the id field as auto increment. Is there a hibernate annotation for this?

Comment: Did you give auto generated while creating table

Comment: The table is generated when the tomcat server starts, is there a jpa annotation? GenerationType.auto doesnt work

Comment: when i try Manually in the mysql workbanch and it gives an error

Comment: can you give the error?.Have you used em.persist to save

Comment: the error: Cannot change column 'ID': used in a foreign key constraint. and I'm using jpa repository for save

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: How did you generated the table? is the id column set as "auto generate"?

Comment: yes. I created table manually with auto generate selected

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link [Hibernate Auto Increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011528/hibernate-auto-increment-id)

You can use GenerationType.AUTO to create .
For details refer link above

Comment: maybe I cant get it to work because I;m using hibernate as a JPA provider and not pure hibernate?